# Simple OAuth2 authentication - Request an access token

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, oauth-2.0

I have been struggling with this now for a while. So if someone could help me it would be great.

I am trying to get a simple access token from the TwitchTV API. I am referring to this link: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication/#getting-tokens

```
GET https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize
?client_id=<your client ID>
&redirect_uri=<your registered redirect URI>
&response_type=<type>
&scope =<space-separated list of scopes>
```

So thats where I begin to struggle already. How exactly do I make such requests in an ASP.NET MVC application? I see that I have an Startup.Auth.cs class where I can configure OAuth Authentications. But how does such authentication have to look like?

It then says in the documentation:

> If the user authorizes your application, the user is sent to your
>   redirect URI, with an ID token and optionally an access token (if that
>   was requested):

```
https://<your registered redirect URI>#id_token=<an id
token>&access_token=<an access token>
```

Now how do I access this token? Can someone please give me a small Code example of how I should start with this API? I really dont have any experience with such technology. How do I have to configure my `Startup.Auth.cs` and how does my Action have to look like, that starts the authentication?

Please refer to the link above in your answer. Thank you!

Comment: Worth studying https://github.com/golf1052/Twixel maybe?

Answer (score -1):

**You can create a redirect URI as callback URL.** 
when a user logged in in your app the callback will be triggered containing the Access Token and other information.

here is the sample snippet in PHP (https://yourhost.com/outhcallback.php)

```
    <?php
       $acccesstoken=$_REQUEST["access_token"];
       $id_token=$_REQUEST["id_token"];
       store_to_session(accesstoken);
    ?>
```

now you have the token. if this token you require in server-side store to the session and if require in client-side store to local storage.

Comment: a hint is a hint, not an answer though, surely? Why not write the code in C#? Don't assume the OP has any idea how to translate PHP to C#.